# What is the replacement for newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder function?

Tags: neo4j

I would like to work with Neo4j packages for java.
I see that the function newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder is deprecated.
What is the best way to work now with Neo4j using java code?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Neo4j 3.0, you'll use the `GraphDatabaseFactory`-

```
graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase( DB_PATH );
```

The Neo4j Java manual is available here: http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/#tutorials-java-embedded

Comment: If I'm using complex queries is this is the right way to work with the Neo4j through Java? Or should I use the rest APIs?

Comment: The question is do you want to work with Neo4j in embedded mode or server mode? If embedded then the java api is suitable. If server, rather than the REST api, I would recommend you use the neo4j java driver http://info.neo4j.com/WBP-PDF-Documentation.html?doc=neo4j-developer-manual-3.0-java&_ga=1.192875886.576249236.1453208740 which uses the binary Bolt protocol. However, Cypher is much advanced and performs much better than earlier versions so you could drop down to the API only when Cypher isn't adequate.